# Echo posted Ajax data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, request

I am using AJAX to post some array data to the server. I get the following expected results in the Firebug network console from the Ajax request.

```
            POST -----> http://example.com/drag_data.php                
            //request header
                Host: example.com
                User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0
                Accept: */*
                Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
                Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
                Referer: http://example.com/drag.php
                Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
                X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
                Content-Length: 90
                Cookie: PHPSESSID=b1lr9he4l2hbcnlkcsebfq2134
                Connection: keep-alive

            //data in the request body
                item[]=1&item[]=3&item[]=2&item[]=4&item[]=5

            //firebug params 
                 item[]:"1"
                 item[]:"3"
                 item[]:"2"
                 item[]:"4"
                 item[]:"5"
```

for infor this is the ajax call which give the expected success message (same as the firebug param output)

```
       $.post({

        data: data,

         type: 'POST',

        url: 'drag_data.php?',

        success:function(result){
        $(".result").html(data);},

        error: function(){
        console.log(arguments);
        }
    });
```

I just want to echo the posted data in the drag_data.php script. I have tried the following test code (as well as (print_r and var_dump) but cannot see any posted data which has baffled me. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong please?

```
drag_data.php test file

                $i = 0;

                //this loop is failing to echo the posted array data from the Ajax request
                foreach ($_POST['item'] as $value) {
                    echo "each".$value;
                    $i++;
                }
                ?>
```

Comment: What is the output of `print_r($_POST)`?

Comment: Its empty which is what is totally baffling me as I can see the data in the firebug params console.

Comment: Could you var_dump($_REQUEST) before foreach loop? I would like to see output of it

Comment: sure---I just added var_dump($_REQUEST);
var_dump($_POST) to the code above the $I =0. Had actually tried that and nothing gets shown but empty arrays>>array(0) { } array(0) { } . Question--might be silly but I'm going mad--but how should I access the drag_data.php file in the browser to see the outputs.

Comment: I am still struggling on this. How should I access the drag_data.php file in the browser to see the php outputs? Is it just a case of adding the (drag_data.php) url into the browser and the posted ajax data should be visible with a print_r or var_dump or echo in the drag_data.php script?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make `url: '/drag_data.php'`, with preceding slash and without `?`.
2. Maybe serializing will help: make `data: JSON.stringify(data)` on client and `json_decode` on server.
3. Check configurations of your server - are requests you're seeing in your firebug actually reaching the server?

Comment: The ? was a cut and paste typo when I was adding the params to the url. Sorry. I did try adding the backslash and it caused the success message to fail. Removing the backslash caused the success message to work.

Comment: hmmm I a do wonder if its a server firewall issue or something like that.

Comment: i will try json because I am getting other json responses on the website successfully executed. Will post back on that one.

Comment: I have changed the ajax call to json...$.ajax({
   
            data: JSON.stringify(data), dataType:"json",

   
   contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8", ETC and i am now getting firebug params output in json  format....a long string. However based ont he above I wasn't to sure what you suggest I do server side. I haven't used json too much.

Comment: I have tried $result = json_decode($data); server side (with and without the true argument). I am not sure $data is correct based on the client side ajax setup (above)?

Comment: I also tried (just to see)  $decoded = json_decode($_GET['data']);
echo "here is".$decoded; again nothing at all. But I am getting the firebug params correctly stringified by json

Answer (score 0):

Finally cracked it. Turns out that there was a server side issue with Ajax calls that has now been resolved by the service provider. So in actual fact my original code works as it should. Maybe this thread or the code will be useful for someone else in the future.